# How to flatten a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['X', '1'],[float('nan'),'2'],[float('nan'),'3'],
        ['Y', '4'],[float('nan'),'5'],[float('nan'),'6']])

     0  1
0    X  1
1  NaN  2
2  NaN  3
3    Y  4
4  NaN  5
5  NaN  6
```

How can I transform that dataframe to flatten the second column into a list/array for each new value in column 0?

After the transform it should look like that:

```
     0  1
0    X  [1,2,3]
3    Y  [4,5,6]
```

Preserving of the index isn't important. Since I'm pandas beginner I have a hard time to solve it without iterating over it with a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) before `GroupBy` + `apply` with `list`:

```
df[0] = df[0].ffill()
res = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list).reset_index()

print(res)

   0          1
0  X  [1, 2, 3]
1  Y  [4, 5, 6]
```

In general, such a data structure is *not* recommended as a series of lists removes the ability to perform vectorised operations. The dtype of your series of lists will be `object`, which can contain pointers to arbitrary types.

Comment: Thank you! ffill helps alot to get rid of the NaN which where my problem before to use group by.